# Will charcoal (carbon) oxidize in the air?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, environmental-chemistry, carbon-family, carbon-dioxide

[Wikipedia — Carbon sequestration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_sequestration) claims that burying charcoal into the soil offsets $\ce{CO2}$ and thus reduces the greenhouse effect:

> In the soil, the biochar carbon is unavailable for oxidation to $\ce{CO2}$ and consequential atmospheric release.

Is it a must to cover charcoal/biochar with the soil to prevent the air and rain water exposure to avoid oxidation, i.e. offset carbon dioxide? Would it otherwise oxidize to $\ce{CO2}$ under normal conditions (no fire) if left above the ground?

Comment: The spontaneous oxidation of charcoal by air at room temperature happens spontaneously. But it is so slow that it can be forgotten. The half-life of the reaction iis much much longer than the duration of the universe.

Comment: slightly related (especially Sir Poliakoff's video "Charcoal in Liquid Oxygen (slow motion)") [Why doesn't carbon fiber overwrapping in LOX catch fire? (watch this video first)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27829/12102)

Comment: So to capture carbon this way you don't necessarily need to bury biochar, you just need to find a meaningful usage for it, correct? And what about water? Can charcoal oxidation be accelerated by regular water contact (like rain/river water)?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59884/at-what-temperature-does-charcoal-burn